# wavesurfer get elapsed time in real time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-audio

I'm using [katspaugh's waveSurfer library](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) for playing sound files.

I wrote code to show 'elapsed time / total time' in this way.

```
waveSurfer.on('play', function() {
   $scope.getCurrentDuration();
});
```

`$scope.getCurrentDuration()` is a function to transform floating-type variable to string-type variable, like below:

```
$scope.getDuration = function() {

  if ($scope.waveSurferReady) {
    var time = waveSurfer.getDuration(); // get duration(float) in second
    var minute = Math.floor(time / 60); // get minute(integer) from time
    var tmp = Math.round(time - (minute * 60)); // get second(integer) from time
    var second = (tmp < 10 ? '0' : '') + tmp; // make two-figured integer if less than 10

    return String(minute + ':' + second); // combine minute and second in string
  }

  else {
    return 'not ready yet'; // waveSurfer is not ready yet
  }
};
```

But the problem is,
 in this part:
`waveSurfer.on('play', function() ...)`
the callback function execute only once.

I expect the callback function called periodically, but it executes only once, so as the result, elapsed time is shown only at the start time.

How can I solve this?

Comment: On the github page, under where the events are listed, it states: "play – When play starts."

Comment: You will probably want to start calling a loop when the 'play' event occurs, maybe with requestAnimationFrame,then also listen for the stop event to cancelAnimationFrame

Comment: Thank you! I will find out what you've told me. and also thanks to Matthias for editing my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking into the [source](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/blob/master/src/mediaelement.js#L44-L46), I've found the `audioprocess` event paired with html5 [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate) event.

Try it out.

```
waveSurfer.on('audioprocess', function() {
   // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just woke up so I will try it out now!